# How to get database name in a server-level DDL trigger

Tags: sql-server, ddl-trigger

I'm creating a Server level trigger that fires after a create table statement, and I want to print the database name and table name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogTempTables
ON ALL SERVER
AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA()
       DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50) 
               = @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
       DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50) = DB_NAME()

       PRINT @Database
       PRINT @TableName
END
GO
```

If I create a table in database ABC123 it prints:

> master
>   
> TestTable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DB_NAME()` will always return the context of the trigger, not the context of the event. But you're in luck: the `EVENTDATA()` contains the object name *and* the database name. Try adding this to your trigger (also you should be very careful about using 50 characters, because both tables and databases can have longer names).

```
DECLARE @db sysname = @EventData.value(N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', N'sysname');
PRINT @db;
```